# Magento Table Rates shipping price is not beeing calculated correctly

Tags: shipping, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart, shopping

I have set up a simple Table Rates for my store.

The rules are based on Price vs Destination. I have it set up:
if the price is lover that 35 then shipping is 2.99 and if higher then 0.

But I don't know why, but Magento calculates it wrong... Please see attached screenshot.

Anyone has a clue why this is happening?

I have the prices (product and shipping) tax included and everything...

I don't get it, it seems like Magento is taking to account the price without Tax and based on that price applies shipping cost's, but I want it to take a subtotal with Tax included and apply the correct shipping cost based on that amount.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thank you,[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento works on tax exclusive shipping amount, you need custom code/extn to do tax inclusive calculation.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't follow. Could you elaborate your answer please.

Comment: When tablerates looks at the price it always looks at the tax-exclusive price (and ignores promotional discounts aswell).

Comment: Ok, I solved it months ago. I thought it was other question. Anyway thank you

Comment: How did you solve this problem , I am facing the same issue for table rates.